# Run cursor through vector while checking its bounds

Tags: c++, vector, cursor

I have a cursor that has its "position" determined by another part of the code. My intention is to have this cursor check through the next and previous object of a vector and check for a condition. If it's valid, the cursor takes this object's position.
Here's some sample code of my idea:

```
class A
{
bool valid;
public:
A(bool v)       {valid=b;}
bool IsValid()  {return valid;}
};

void CheckNearbyValidity()
{
    /*if the object to the right is valid, update position to this object*/
    if(exampleVector.at(cursor-1).IsValid())
    {
        /*do stuff*/
        cursor = (cursor-1);
    }
    /*if the object to the right isnt valid, try the same thing to the left*/
    else if(exampleVector.at(position+1).IsValid())
    {
        /*do stuff*/
        cursor = (cursor+1);
    }

    /*leave if none are valid*/
}
```

The problem I encounter here is that if the cursor is at the start or end of the vector, checking the if conditions will cause it to throw an out of range exception.

My solution was to check if the new cursor position was valid before querying the vector:

```
 void CheckNearbyValidity()
 {
     /*if the object to the right is valid, update position to this object*/
     if(cursor-1 >= 0)
     {
        if(exampleVector.at(cursor).IsValid())
        {
            /*do stuff*/
            cursor = (cursor-1);
        }
    }
    /*new position makes the next condition always true and returns cursor to the same position*/
    if(cursor-1 < exampleVector.size())
    {
        if(exampleVector.at(cursor+1).IsValid())
        {
        /*do stuff*/
        cursor = (cursor+1);
        }
    }
    /*leave if none are valid*/
}
```

The new problem was that since I could no longe use "else", both conditions would be valid and the cursor would remain where it started.

My workaround to this problem was to surround the function in a while loop, and break when necessary:

```
void CheckNearbyValidity()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(cursor-1 >= 0)
        {
            if(exampleVector.at(cursor-1).IsValid())
            {
                /*do stuff*/
                position = (cursor-1);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(cursor-1 >= 0)
        {
            if(exampleVector.at(cursor+1).IsValid())
            {
                /*do stuff*/
                position = (cursor+1);
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

My question is, **is the "single" while loop approach a bad idea? Is there a better way to manipulate this cursor?**

Comment: How about a return below `cursor = (cursor-1);` and `cursor = (cursor+1);`?

Comment: The real function actually has more stuff before and after this part. I guess it's a good idea to separate the function logic into more functions so that I can take this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should harness the power of `&&`:

```
    if (cursor-1 >= 0 && 
        exampleVector.at(cursor-1).IsValid())
    {
        /*do stuff*/
        position = (cursor-1);
    }
    else if (cursor+1 < exampleVector.size() && 
             exampleVector.at(cursor+1).IsValid())
    {
        /*do stuff*/
        position = (cursor+1);
    }
```

This allows you to connect the two statements together as an `if-else` as you had originally, only with the additional validation step checking `cursor` against the vector bounds.

The `&&` performs short-circuit evaluation.  If `cursor-1 >= 0` evaluates to `false`, then the code skips evaluating `exampleVector.at(cursor-1).IsValid()` and jumps immediately to evaluating the `else` clause.

Likewise, in the `else if` clause, if `cursor+1 < exampleVector.size()` evaluates to `false`, the `&&` short-circuits and the code skips evaluating `exampleVector.at(cursor+1).IsValid()`, again making it safe.

Comment: I totally assumed both expressions would be evaluated beforehand, causing the vector to throw an exception, and didn't even try that approach. This solves the problem and cleans up a lot of code. Thanks!

Comment: The short circuit evaluation for `&&` and `||` was one of the coolest things I learned in C when I first encountered it *mumblety* years ago.  ONE CAVEAT:  If you have a class that overloads `&&` or `||`, the overloaded operators _lose_ their short-circuit mojo for that class.  So, kids, don't overload those operators unless you _really_ know what you're doing.  (And even then, think twice, and then think again.)